# How to hide a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I've got a wordpress website and i need to hide for the moment some custom post type.

I want to hide it because we will need it later.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a parameter named "public" where you can set if you want the custom post type to be private or public

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'acme_product',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
        'public' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Hansy, thanks for your response. Does this work with the existing custom post type? How should I use this function? where should I run it? Sorry, I'm not familiar with wordpress. Thanks

Comment: Hello Syd, well, how are you adding these custom post types? I think you may be using a plugin?

Comment: They are already there. I need to hide it for a while, there is no plugin.

Comment: Ok, so i guess is added using the theme, you may need to check your functions.php file within the theme, and look and any line that containts register_post_type

Comment: Sorry Hansy, there is not this function inside function.php in the theme folder. What can i do?

Comment: Hmm, what theme - plugins are you using? i may need those to help you (i do think we may need to go to chat )